# Reconciling client / server state without client-side IDs

Tags: javascript, client-server, react-redux

I have a react/redux based drawing application with live editing. When a user starts drawing a new square (for example) it is added to a local object collection and displayed. When the user finishes drawing a POST is dispatched to the server to persist the entity.

Because the object is added locally before the request is sent/completes, my local and server state are out of sync.

In a previous version of the application I was able to rely on client-side assigned IDs for these objects to reconcile local and server state. I could compare which objects existed and were being updated, which were new and which had been removed, by ID. Now however there is a requirement to use server assigned IDs exclusively.

Because redux updates may come in at any time, including during the inflight POST request, I need a way to reliably compare local objects and state with the newest server data provided through redux.

What are some strategies for reconciling local and server state without client controlled ids?